# Does Kubernetes ingress support wildcard domains?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm reading through:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/8
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41881

But I can't seem to determine a conclusive answer. Does Kubernetes support wildcard domains in it's ingress or not? If not, what are the possible workaround approaches?

At least for V1.18 it seems to be officially suported - though still dependent on the ingress controllers also supporting it. (https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/) - though I still want to know about recent previous versions as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you said it’s up to each individual controller but all of them do that I know of.

Comment: If they all did it, they were would be no reason to announce v.1.18 supporting it.

Comment: It was not previously part of the spec, but the spec has only ever been a minimum requirement and all controllers support things beyond it, but not always the same way. For example some support regexes for path, some support globs, some neither.